How to iterate over asynchronous code sequentially in Combine
I have a protocol defined as follows:
protocol Prompter {
    func promptIfNeeded() async -> Bool
}

And an array of Prompter conforming types:
var prompters: [Prompter] { [PrompterA(), PrompterB()] }

Currently, I iterate through this array, prompting each message to the user, one by one, using async await:
for prompter in prompters {
    let result = await prompter.promptIfNeeded()
    print("The result is \(result)")
}

However, I’m curious about leveraging Combine publishers instead of async await. Any guidance on this?
Note - each prompt must wait for the previous one to finish

How do you want to "leverage" publishers? Do you want to remove all async/await from your code? i.e. change promptIfNeeded to return Future instead? Or do you want to wrap the current promptIfNeeded with a publisher and replace the for loop with Combine operators? Or, keep all the async stuff, but consume the sequence of Bools as a AnyPublisher<Bool, Never>?

@Sweeper I want to remove all async/await and to use Future. Thanks!

If you want them to execute sequentially, you can use a Publishers.Sequence with a flatMap with a Subscribers.Demand of .max(1). Obviously, the method would need to return a Future. So, perhaps:
protocol Prompter {
    func promptIfNeeded() -> Future<Bool, Never>
}

struct PrompterA: Prompter {
    func promptIfNeeded() -> Future<Bool, Never> {
        Future { promise in
            …
            promise(.success(result)) // where `result` is some `Bool`
        }
    }
}

struct PrompterB: Prompter { … }

class Foo {
    var cancellables: Set<AnyCancellable> = []
    
    func performPrompts() {
        let prompters: [Prompter] = [PrompterA(), PrompterB()]

        Publishers.Sequence(sequence: prompters)
            .flatMap(maxPublishers: .max(1)) { $0.promptIfNeeded() }
            .sink { print($0) }
            .store(in: &cancellables)
    }
}

There are other variations on the theme, but hopefully this illustrates the idea: In Combine, one can use flatMap with a maxPublishers of .max(1)) for sequential behavior.

IMHO, I find the async-await code to be a vast improvement upon the above, but I wanted to answer your question and you can decide which you prefer.

Thanks! Why do you prefer async/await over Combine here?

I find the for loop to be far more intuitive than the above. Using async-await has less syntactic noise (no need for sinks, cancellables, futures, etc.), has a nice linear flow rather than relying on closures, retires Result-like types, etc. Combine was the best thing around when it was introduced in 2019, but when Swift concurrency was introduced in 2021, it somewhat diminished the utility of Combine. It is a bit unusual to see someone ask to refactor Swift concurrency code to the older Combine patterns. But, again, you are free to use whatever you want.

Hey, if you’re in a Combine-heavy codebase, and want to keep everything using that pattern, then that’s great. And Combine has a more declarative vibe, making it a comfortable fit within SwiftUI codebase, too. But if you’ve got a async-await codebase, I wouldn’t be inclined to just refactor it to Combine without a fairly compelling case.
